# How to call a class from a function which is inside another class?

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

class MyPracticeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Debit()

class Debit(Widget):
    def debit(self):
        return Hello()


class Hello(Widget):
    pass



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyPracticeApp().run()
```

## kv file...

```
<Debit>
    Button:
        text : 'popup'
        size_hint : 0.2,0.2
        on_press : root.debit()

<Hello>:
    Button:
        text : 'popup2'
        size_hint : 0.2,0.2
       # on_press : root.debit()
```

There is a button popup, and when I press this button I am calling the `debit()` function. Inside the debit function I am calling `Hello()`, but I'm unable to get anything from this class. What am I doing wrong?

Whenever I click on a buttton I want a new screen but without screen navigation. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question Kivy Factory

> what is the concept of Factory in kivy

### Answer

When the keyword `Factory` is used anywhere (e.g. kv file, or Python script) in your project, it will automatically register any class or module and instantiate them.

### Example

The following example illustrates the use of `Factory` in the *kv* file to register and instantiate `Popup` widget, *Hello*. There is no class definition of *Hello* and no definition for method `debit()` in Python script.

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Debit>:
    Button:
        text : 'popup'
        size_hint : 0.2,0.2
        on_press : Factory.Hello().open()

<Hello@Popup>:
    title: 'Popup2'
    auto_dismiss: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Hello Kivy'
        Button:
            text : 'Close Popup'
            size_hint : 1,0.2
            on_press : root.dismiss()
""")


class Debit(Widget):
    pass


class MyPracticeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Debit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyPracticeApp().run()
```

## References: [Kivy » Factory object](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.factory.html)

## Question 1

> There is a button popup, and when I press this button I am calling the
>   debit() function. Inside the debit function I am calling Hello(), but
>   I'm unable to get anything from this class. What am I doing wrong?

### Explanation

The second button is not displayed because the app did not have instructions on  what to do with the instantiated object, `Hello` which contains a child widget, `Button`.

### Solution

One of the solution is to add the new object using `add_widget()` function.

#### Snippets - Py

```
def debit(self):
    return self.add_widget(Hello())
```

## Question 2

> Whenever I click on a button I want a new screen but without screen
>   navigation. How do I do this ?

### Solution

You could use Kivy `Popup` widget.

### Example

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Debit>:
    Button:
        text : 'popup'
        size_hint : 0.2,0.2
        on_press : root.debit()

<Hello>:
    title: 'Hello Popup2'
    auto_dismiss: False
    Button:
        text : 'Close Popup'
        size_hint : 0.2,0.2
        on_press : root.dismiss()
""")


class Debit(Widget):
    def debit(self):
        return Hello().open()


class Hello(Popup):
    pass


class MyPracticeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Debit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyPracticeApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: App Startup]
[image: Popup]

Comment: @ ikolim  thanks for your help.  Its working....   can you explain me what is the concept of Factory in kivy.......

Comment: Please refer to updated post for details on Kivy Factory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ScreenManager` for this.
A little example:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """

#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "top"
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        transition: NoTransition()
        Screen:
            name: "screen1"
            Button:
                text: "screen 2"
                on_release: sm.current = "screen2"
        Screen:
            name: "screen2"
            Button:
                text: "screen 1"
                on_release: sm.current = "screen1"
    Label:
        text: "bottom"
"""

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: I do not want to use ScreenManager ...Suppose there are 4 buttons at the top left corner  debit, credit, profile,setting.. And there are some images at the bottom. When I click on debit button I do not want to slide the screen but want to change the view of screen and so on for the others button.  Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rahulcharan I updated the answer to do just that. Still screenmanager is the way. You can nest widgets as much as you lik ein kivy.

Comment: @Rahulcharan no problem

Comment: And suppose If I want to add some logic in screen 1 and if this logic is true then I want to go screen 2 otherwise I want to remain on screen 1....How do I do this?

Comment: can you suggest me a good kivy tutorial from where I can learn kivy from scratch...Reading official documentation is very difficult for me ...

Comment: @rahulcharan I can suggest this https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdNh1e1kmiPP4YApJm8ENK2yMlwF1_edq . And for the logic, you could do something like this on the screenmanager `current: "screen1" if some_boolean_var else "screen2"` but that needs to be run after the screens are added. It will throw an error as is.

Comment: @rahulcharan No problem :) I will suggest making new questions where you specify your problem, rather than answer your own questions with a question